# Execute PHP get request through terminal

Tags: php, cron, terminal, debian

I'm currently running cronjobs for several people, to know who are those people i give it a parameter with some details :

```
0 1 * * * cd /var/www; php auto.php?user=user
```

for some reason it returns this result :

> Could not open input file: auto.php?user=user

is there anything wrong with the syntax ? do i have to encode anything ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using parameters in command line PHP is different

the command should be

`php auto.php myuser`

then in the script you access the variables using the `$_SERVER['argv']` superglobal array - each command line argument is in order in that array starting with the script name. You can check the number of arguments passed with `$_SERVER['argc']`

in this instance

```
$_SERVER['argc'] = 2
$_SERVER['argv'][0] = auto.php
$_SERVER['argv'][1] = myuser
```

**bonus info**

you can add a `#!/usr/bin/php` (called a shebang) to the first line of the php file, add the execute bit, then you don't have to invoke php on the command line you can just call the script. Assuming that php is located in the typical location of /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 2):

The questionmark indicates a HTTP GET parameter, which does not make sense on the terminal, because no web server is involved. You can use this:

```
cd /var/www; php auto.php some parameters
```

And then use `$_SERVER['argc']` and `$_SERVER['argv']` within the PHP script to read the parameters.

Comment: This is the full example, "some" and "parameters" are parameters. Try `var_dump($_SERVER['argv'])` in the script to see how this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a php script from the command line with url-style parameters, but there are a couple of possible solutions:

You can use wget to effectively trigger the script via the webserver (assuming it's actually a page/script running in the server)

```
0 1 * * * wget http://yourserver/thepath/auto.php?user=user
```

Using php's [getopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) extension you modify the script to accept shell-style parameters

```
$options = getopt("u:");  // expect -u followed by the parameter value
$user = $options["u"];
// continue the script
```

which is called as

```
php -q auto.php -u user
```

Check out the getopt documentation page, you can make it a lot fancier than this as well.  The main advantage of using getopt over using argc/argv (which remains a valid option btw) is that it's a lot easier to handle multiple parameters that can be given in any order.  Eg, assume you need:

```
php -q auto.php -u user -p pass -a another -b whatever
```

you will need to write quite some supporting code to parse these parameters, and getopt does that all by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this that way - it's the way of passing arguments in http request, not everywhere. For command line you have to use `$_SERVER['argv']` and `$_SERVER['argc']`.

in your case you should rework your code a bit. In place of

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
```

use

```
$user = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
```

and should change the way you invoke your script to:

```
0 1 * * * cd /var/www; php auto.php user
```

You can also may find some command line helper classes useful, i.e.: [CLI](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/954-PHP-CLI-is-shell-argument-parsing-and-handling-class.html)

See [Command Line Usage](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) section in PHP manual for more information.